# Use email as username with django-registration

Tags: django, django-registration, django-1.5

I am trying to use an email address as the username (using Django 1.5's custom user model) along with django-registration.

The docs for version 1.0 of django-registration say:-

> the base view classes are deliberately user-model-agnostic. Simply subclass them, and implement logic for your custom user model

I have subclassed the registration view but unfortunately, it looks like the RegistrationProfile still expects the user model to have a username field which mine doesn't. I just have email (as well as first name, last name etc.)

Is this a bug? It looks to me like django-registration still needs the default base user model to be in use - it's just able to use a custom user model that ADDS to the base model.

Is there any way round it? Maybe I can subclass the registration profile as well? How would I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think things will be easier in the long run if you keep using the default user profile. If you are only trying to add the ability to log in with an email address, I recommend creating a new authentication backend:

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class EmailModelBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email__iexact=username)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

You would then need to that backend to your settings.py:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'yourproject.yourapp.yourmodule.EmailModelBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
)
```

Comment: How does this help with using django registration?

Answer (score 1):

As-is, it's complicated. You need to:

- [apply this patch](https://bitbucket.org/LinnTroll/django-registration-1.5/commits/c71d5b8e273551cffdfc7869545430e3) because in d-r-1.0, models.py assumes your User model has a "username" field
- create your own "backend" by copy/pasting/editing registration/backends/default/views.py
- copy/paste/edit the registration form as well from registration/forms.py
- most of the time you can use the registration views without modification

The question is about custom User and Django 1.5, so i think django-registration-email is a bad answer. Thisi is for Django <1.5, creating fake usernames and turning around the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you out:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-registration-email/0.5.1

They've implemented this in django-registration

Comment: That does look good. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work with custom user models.

`Manager isn't available; User has been swapped for 'thursdayfootball.Player'`